# Determine a pointer type at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I'm trying to extract the class type from a pointer passed into a macro. Here's what i have so far

```
template <class CLASS> class getter
{
public:
    typedef CLASS type;
};
template <class CLASS> getter<CLASS> func(const CLASS* const)
{
    return getter<CLASS>();
}
...
#define GETTYPE(PTR) func(p)::type
...
MyClass *p = new MyClass;
...
GETTYPE(p) myClass;
```

Is this even possible? Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: So basically what you want is to strip the pointer in the template?

Comment: `std::remove_pointer<>::type`?

Comment: Yes but given a pointer, not a pointer type

Comment: @cppguy: If I understand you right, then you will need something in the lines of `decltype`. How do you get a pointer whose static type is not know, I'd rather not ask...

Comment: I can't use remove_pointer because I don't know what the template argument would be. Just that I have a variable I know is a pointer

Comment: @cppguy: At that point, you surely know a *name* for the type. C++ is statically typed, so you cannot have a variable of a type that is not known to the compiler... you just need to use whatever the alias for the name is in the context of the variable.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas No, the cal to func in my example would live inside a macro being passed a pointer. I'll modify the example to show the use

Comment: As @K-ballo mentioned, you need something like `decltype` or [`BOOST_TYPEOF`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/typeof.html).

Comment: Unless you add more context, to how you intend on using this, it makes no sense.

Comment: Wow, downvoted because there's no answer? @K-ballo was correct. I am trying to reproduce a combination of remove_pointer and decltype in pre C++11. If there is no answer, just say so

Comment: There is an answer: `BOOST_TYPEOF` + `boost::remove_pointer<>`. Downvoted because we had to prod every relevant piece of information out of you instead of just volunteering it initially (not to mention the whole X=Y thing...).

Comment: Thank you for the BOOST_TYPEOF information. I will investigate that. In the future, how about a little leniency on somebody asking a question and not knowing how to word it. I honestly don't think I deserved the downvote

Comment: Evil coding style, using "CLASS" inside a template!  I only use "class", regardless of case, for defining and declaring classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `decltype` in C++11.

Comment: using visual studio 2005... no decltype unfortunately. That's what I'm trying to reproduce

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. You can extract from a generic type that you *know* it is a template what is the pointed type. But you cannot do it with a function. A simple implementation is `std::remove_pointer` in C++11, that is implemented in the lines of:

```
template <typename T>
struct remove_ptr {       // Non pointer generic implementation
   typedef T type;
};
template <typename T>
struct remove_ptr<T*> {   // Ptr specialization:
   typedef T type;
};
```

Use:

```
template <typename T> void foo( T x ) {
   typedef typename remove_ptr<T>::type underlying_type;
}
int main() {
   foo( (int*)0 ); // underlying_type inside foo is int
   foo( 0 );       // underlying_type inside foo is also int
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not what I need. I need access to the type at the same level that the pointer exists like in my example above

Comment: @cppguy: C++ is a strong and statically typed language. At the place where the variable is in scope you have the type of the variable. You don't need to access it through the pointer since you *know* the type. Do you care to explain *how* can you not have the type?

Comment: I have updated the example above to show how I mean to use this code David. At the time the macro is called, I do not know the pointer type

Comment: @cppguy: You are not showing *why* you need the macro, what do you intend on doing with it

Comment: I intend to use the return of the macro to scope a pointer to member function like this &GETTYPE(p)::type::SomeFuncName

Comment: `template <typename T> int (T::*somFuncPtr( T* p )) { return &T::someFuncName; }` (assuming that the member pointer is to an `int` data member, you can change the code for any other type including functions

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13083/discussion-between-cppguy-and-david-rodriguez-dribeas)

Comment: I was away from the computer (on my way home). You have not added any extra information in the chat, so I don't have much to comment.